# "protocol String.Chars not implemented " even when I'm using "inspect"

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have an action:

```
def my_action(conn, params) do
  # ..............

  Logger.info("test: params #{IO.inspect(params)};\r\n\r\n")
```

This causes an exception:

```
  ** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol String.Chars not implemented for %{"key1" => "var1", "key2" => "var2", # ........}. 
      This protocol is implemented for: Atom, BitString.................
```

I comprehend what it means, but I can't understand why it's caused? I'm using "inspect". What should I use instead to fix it?

Answer (score 12):

`IO.inspect` prints the value and then returns the value. Other than printing the value, it's the same as writing

```
"test: params #{params};\r\n\r\n"
```

What you need here is `Kernel.inspect` or simply `inspect`:

```
Logger.info("test: params #{inspect(params)};\r\n\r\n")
```

Comment: is `Kernel.inspect` is the same as `inspect`? I mean, do they live in the same module?

Comment: Yes, the `Kernel` module is imported by default in all Elixir modules so `inspect` is the same as `Kernel.inspect`.